# How to call a javascript method from an apex method to display a button

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, commandbutton

I have a use case where I have a button "Add another". I want this button to be hidden until an apex method "Save" is called. The save method calls a javascript method which in turn displays the button.

Here is my visualforce code:

```
<b><apex:commandButton id="Save" styleClass="slds-button slds-button-- 
neutral btn-lg" value="Save" action="{!saveRecord}" rerender=""/></b>


<div id="addnew" style="display:none;">

<b><apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral btn-lg" 
action="{!AddNew}" value="Add Another" immediate="true" /></b>

<br></br>

</div>

<script>

  function func()

   {


    $("#addnew").show();

   }

<script>
```

Apex Class:

```
public string callfunc{get;set;}
public pagereference saveRecord() {


     ................ 
     ................
      callfunc= '<script> func(); </script>';


      return null;

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats not the way, javascript methods are getting called.

Your use case can be solved this way.

**Controller**

Create a Boolean property as follows.

```
public Boolean displayAddNew {get;set;}
```

In the `saveMethod()` make it true. `(displayAddNew = true)`.

**Visualforce** code needs to be changed as follows:

Render Add New Button based on `{!displayAddNew}`

In the save button `rerender="addNewBtnPnl"`

```
<apex:commandButton id="Save" styleClass="slds-button slds-button-- 
neutral btn-lg" value="Save" action="{!saveRecord}" rerender="addNewBtnPnl"/>


<apex:outputPanel id="addNewBtnPnl" style="display:none;">

<b><apex:commandButton rendered="{!displayAddNew }"  
styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral btn-lg" 
action="{!AddNew}" 
value="Add Another" 
immediate="true" /></b>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: one thing to note about the original markup, using `immediate=true` on the command button causes form data not to be posted and may cause some undesired side effects with the data being captured by the input fields on the page

Comment: correct you are, thats why I think, it needs to be wrapped with actionRegion